# R: ggplot with datetime on x axis

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot 5 days of historical stock data in R using ggplot. Datetime on the x axis, and the stock values ('close') on the y axis. I only want to show the minutes of the day when the stock market is open, and my data set is limited to 7 hours a day of values x 5 days.

But when I plot it with ggplot, the scale is changed so I get all the hours per day.

```
ggplot(data = df_stock, aes(x = datetime, y = close)) +
  geom_line()
```

I've tried googling this and using the R help function. I'm quite new to R so my apologies if this is very easy to solve. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a minimal example would be helpful to address this question, a more general answer which could be useful can be given.

`ggplot2` does not have a facility for axis-breaking, as it's not considered good practice. However what you're doing here is actually a transformation of the variable --- hours open rather than hours of the day. So you'll have to transform the variable itself. You can do this using the `lubridate` package. Let's take two days and imagine the market is open between 10am and 5pm.

```
require(lubridate)
dates <- c("2014-01-01 10:00:00 UTC", "2014-01-01 13:00:00 UTC", "2014-01-01 17:00:00 UTC", "2014-01-02 13:00:00 UTC", "2014-01-02 17:00:00 UTC")
dates <- ymd_hms(dates)
```

Now you will need to scale the data to only have the times you want. You can call the parts of the date with `lubridate', and divide by the hours in the day, where here they are 24 rather than 7.

```
hour(dates) <- hour(dates)-10
scaleddates <- day(dates)-1 + hour(dates)/7 + minute(dates)/60/7 + second(dates)/60/60/7
scaleddates
[1] 0.0000000 0.4285714 1.0000000 1.4285714 2.0000000
```

Now you can plot the graph, with the x-axis reading 'Days' rather than 'Dates'. The x-axis is now how far you are through the working day.